# Running an Android emulator on a Azure VM - I'm getting some errors while starting the emulator

Tags: appium, emulators

Below is the error I'm getting.

So how am I supposed to access BIOS on a AZURE VM?

Or is there any other alternative ways for emulators?

My ultimate goal is to run Appium test on a android emulator.

[image]

Comment: Does the VM in question support virtualization - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/acu ?

Comment: Yeah it says D-v3 and E-v3 have virtualization so on the above test i was using a D2-v3 VM

Answer (score 1):

[Configure nested virtualization manually](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/nested-virtualization)

1. On the Azure VM, open PowerShell as an Administrator.
2. Enable the Hyper-V feature and Management Tools.
3. Open PowerShell and run

PS command:

```
Install-WindowsFeature -Name Hyper-V -IncludeManagementTools -Restart
```

This command restarts the Azure VM. You will lose your RDP connection during the restart process.After the Azure VM restarts, reconnect to your VM using RDP.

Then [install HAXM](https://github.com/intel/haxm/wiki/Installation-Instructions-on-Windows).